# Error: No available formula with the name "ethereum"

Tags: brew

The basic download instructions on the Ethereum repo are producing this brew error: `Error: No available formula with the name "ethereum"`.

Things I've done:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install ethereum
```

Any suggestions or am I missing something?